# Disabling Azure Function multiple simultaneous triggers

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I have an Azure Function App with 7 Functions written in Node.js, deployed though Bitbucket CI and the following `host.json`-file at the root of the project:

```
{
    "id": "...",
    "queues": {
        // retrieve only 1 queue message at a time
        "batchSize": 1,
        "maxDequeueCount": 1,
        "newBatchThreshold": 0
    }
}
```

As far as I know, this should make sure that only 1 queue-triggered function is triggered at a time.

However, If I put the following statement in my function:

```
context.log(`Started processing at ${new Date()}`);
```

I still have some cases with the exact same start time for 2 queue messages.

Any idea what I am missing?
Is this `batchSize` property used per function or per queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the [host.json documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json), you can see that batchSize is per (job) function.

Here's where Azure Functions pulls the batch, in [queue listener](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/56b5302dda3ff6d671fb7e4c1b9ddcce0594a9a2/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Queues/Listeners/QueueListener.cs#L146).

There is a separate queue listener created per QueueTrigger binding, so `batchSize` is per-function. In this case, as you have 7 functions triggering from the same queue, you could have as many as 7 queue messages processing simultaneously on this instance in separate function executions.

I verified by writing a webjobs console app that has two functions triggered from the same queue. I could see that there were two separate QueueListener objects (via `GetHashCode`), one for each function, listening on the same queue simultaneously.

Why do you want to disable simultaneous execution?

Comment: To be clear, I have 7 functions, with 3 of them having a queue trigger, but all of them have a separate queue to work with. So you could say I have 1 function working with 1 specific queue and still dequeueing multiple messages at once. I am actually writing a web scraper so I need to execute my functions sequentially until I have  nothing left in my queue. The ideal way would be a timer trigger combined with my queue messages and only fire my functions every X seconds, but 1 at a time using a queue trigger is good enough, if it would work like I expect it to. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Also, I tried adding a `setTimeout()` to the end of my function before calling `context.done()` to trie throttling my functions to 10 seconds but that doesn't help, a new message gets dequeued before my timeout is reached.

Comment: All the comments Matt made are a correct description of how those config knobs affect processing on a single host instance. However, if your Function App is scaling out (as it will automatically when running in the Consumption plan) then you will get concurrency across different VM instances. Those knobs are per instance not global. Are you running in consumption?

Comment: @mathewc Yes I am running in consumption. Will running it on a dedicated plan help anything?

Comment: @Schaemelhout yes, as you can guarantee the number of concurrent instances (in this case, you would like only one). Consumption will add instances if the app is under enough load.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clear info! Now I just need to decide if I want to pay ~€47.06/mo for a Basic plan just to be able to set a limit to 1 concurrent instance...

Comment: No problem. You can also experiment with Free & Shared plans - those are limited to one function app instance as well, you won't see any horizontal scaling.

Comment: @MattMason-MSFT I'm sorry to keep this discussion going in the comments, but could you explain why my function starts scaling horizontally when I set the `batchSize` and `maxDequeueCount` of 1? I don't see a reason why it should start additional instances?

Comment: The unit of deployment is a function app - which means that if any function in the function app requires scaling, you will get a new instance with all the functions in that app. Also, scaling is dependent on factors such as queue length - if you set `batchSize` and `maxDequeueCount` to 1, but your queue length is long, our scale controller will add new instances to try to handle the load.